# Unable to save PHP output into text file?

Tags: php

I have created a script that extract certain length of array from a given and print_r the result. This is my code.

```
  <?php
header("Content-Type:text/html");
$i=0;
$file= fopen("list.txt","r");
$get=0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $get.= fgets($file);
}
    $explode= explode(" ", $get);

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($explode); $i++)
{
    if(strlen($explode[$i])==17)
    {
       $result = print_r($explode[$i]);

       file_put_contents('result.txt',$result);

    }

}
?>
```

Everything is going good but I want output in a text file. For that I'm using file_put_contents() Function but it is display binary number (1,2) in the text file. Can anyone tell me how to save my output into text file?
Please, be specific, try to use my code and tell me the best one! Just tell me what should I do with this section of code below:

```
> if(strlen($explode[$i])==17)
>          {
>             $result = print_r($explode[$i]);
>          
>             file_put_contents('result.txt',$result);
>              
>         }
```

Comment: What is the value of $serial? I can't see it anywhere else but at the put contents

Comment: can you reformat your question and lose the `>` stitch?

Comment: @Andreas I tried Serial but serial was returning some random string to txt file. I'm new to this function actually.

Comment: Some random string? You have obviously more code than we see here then. What is $serial?

Comment: And what does this do?  `$result = print_r($explode[$i]);`

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I edit the code. now its okay. $result = print_r($explode[$i]); This code is for taking the exploded array into one variable. I did this so that I can pass the $result as argument into file_put_contents function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ya. I did that.

Comment: I see your edit now but it's still a mess. What is in list.txt and what do you need to get done? Be specific now.

Comment: Also, maybe that is just me that find it confusing. But don't name variables the same as functions. When I'm read `$explode[$i]` I read as you want to explode $i

Comment: @Andreas List.txt contains whole text including mac address of some devices. That's a part of my project actually. I have to fetch mac addresses of the connected devices to my laptop hostspot through cmd. Which I did. Then I transfer the data on cmd to txt file, which list.txt... Now LIst.txt contains lots of unnecessary info also which I don't needed. So for this I created this PHP script. where explode function turns the whole text into array, then by using "($strlen[$i])==17", it returns the array with length 17; which mac address. Now I want that output in another text file.

Comment: Not specifc enough. Specific means you copy part of the file and show us it. Then you show what the expected output should look like. I think your code can be improved a bit.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you bro for your patience. I got the answer. Thanks for replying me back every time.

Comment: I'm just saying there are probably miles of improvements that can be done to your file. I will give a try and make a blind guess since you are not willing to share input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the file that is being displayed on the screen, just put the same $explode[$i] inside the file_put_contents:

```
if(strlen($explode[$i])==17)
{
    $result = print_r($explode[$i]);

    file_put_contents('result.txt',$explode[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! Thank you so much bro. But it is overriding the text written in a text file. How to use APPEND_FILE function in that?

Comment: Its done anyways. I use FILE_APPEND function and it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will open the list.txt and save it all to $data.
Look for Mac addresses and save them to the array $macs.
Then arrange them with new lines and save them to result.txt. 
Three lines of code instead of sixteen.

```
$data = file_get_contents("list.txt");

Preg_match_all("/([0-9A-Fa-f:-]{17})/", $data, $macs);

File_put_contents("result.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $macs[1]));
```